# mithriljs component state not update for callback or promise

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I use mithriljs component state like this :

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    let ExpenseAmount = 0;
    let IncomeAmount = 0;
    let UserFullname = '';

    const getExpense = () => {
        ExpenseAmount = 1000;
    };

    const getIncome = () => {
        IncomeAmount = 2000;
    };

    const getUserFullname = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('calling fullname');
            UserFullname = 'Mike'; //<----
        }, 1000);
    }

    getUserFullname();

    return {
        view: () => [
            m("div", { class: "container-fluid flex-grow-1 container-p-y" }, [
                m(
                    "h4",
                    {
                        class:
                            "media align-items-center font-weight-bold py-3 mb-4"
                    },
                    [
                        m("img", {
                            src: "assets/img/avatars/1.png",
                            class: "ui-w-50 rounded-circle"
                        }),
                        m("div", { class: "media-body ml-3" }, [
                            m("span", `Welcome back, ${UserFullname}!`),
                            m(
                                "div",
                                { class: "text-muted text-tiny mt-1" },
                                m(
                                    "small",
                                    { class: "font-weight-normal" },
                                    `Today is ${new Date().toDateString()}`
                                )
                            )
                        ])
                    ]
                )
            ])
        ]
    };
};
```

I wish I can call and `ajax` function and callback/promise from it will update the `UserFullname`.
But it not work. I tried simplified it with setTimeout, it still not working.

how to solve update state in ajax call or priomise or setTimeout?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mithril [will not know to redraw](https://mithril.js.org/autoredraw.html#when-mithril-does-not-redraw) once the data changes have taken place - so you'll need to tell it to by calling [`m.redraw()`](https://mithril.js.org/redraw.html) at the end of the `getUserFullname` function body.

Where you currently have:

```
const getUserFullname = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    UserFullname = 'Mike';
  }, 1000);
}
```

You should instead write:

```
const getUserFullname = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    UserFullname = 'Mike';

    m.redraw();
  }, 1000);
}
```

[Here's a working demo with the fix highlighted](https://flems.io/#0=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-xiMwCb1Iex6YWBipwFgvxQHGtCJsm2SphSaCUOEeFQBhWF0Te5yiBgYiSBAcCSN+NoEpIAAiE4wLIEGUHxdAAMo0OE-yfDIrQ3qBUIyPJkiKUemEqXR6nHppyxoK0ELXmej4wOQSHUAgiAgPUADsiCzB6ICtHOZBQP8yLmagICgowoZupJUAGQK-kWamNCGHAiCkuwhjIpWnjElgPl+QAAhaFoAGzxYl0BEKQIA0GIxh4HA5CSYYNAOXOrRAA).